# How to build an API without sensible field using Doctrine2?

Tags: web-services, doctrine-orm, soa

I'm actually using Doctrine2 within a Zend Framework project.

I'm build an API to be used as a Restfull webservice, and I'm actually using an Entity Serializer and/or an Array result.

However my problem is my entity are fully serialized therefore fields like password or email are returned.

It is not a problem when working on a private call but it is for public API.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had you think about this alternatives:

- Encrypt the sensible information
- Use a secure https connection
- Return a copy of the bean without the information you want (libraries like dozer of morph can do the job).

The last option in fact is a good pratice, cause sometimes it's not a good idea to use an Entity Bean in the presentation, service, or API layer.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, encrypt the information, it is done for password (well it's hashed) but not really convenient for email, https is used but the end user may still get the result, the last option is indeed the right solution, however I don't really know how to implement it without impacting performance.

Comment: Don't know if Dozer or morph allows caching transformations; they use reflection API and yes, that could be slow. But making a raw copy of your beans (like returnedBean.setX(entityBean.getX()); shouldn't affect the global performance (1 object in heap + n instructions).